# Change 'Please match the format requested.' to something else?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, form-for, form-with

Is there an easy way to customise the message that appears when the `pattern: "([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)"` argument is not satisfied and this message appears:

[image: > Please match the format requested]

e.g.

```
<%= f.text_field :username, pattern: "([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)" %>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a "title" attribute to append on to that message:

```
<%= f.text_field :username, pattern: "([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)" , title: "Letters, numbers, hyphen, and underscore Only"%>
```

This will result in the following message:

> Please match the format requested: Letters, numbers, hyphen, and underscore Only

Otherwise, for more custom messages, you can use client side validation (via [javascript](https://www.cssscript.com/best-javascript-form-validator/)) server side validations (via [rails and ActiveModel](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html))

Comment: For reference, what it results in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/poNdS.png

Comment: @stevec much better. I never include images in my post because the links die.

Answer (score 5):

For a fully custom message you must use JavaScript.

```js
const username = document.querySelector("#user_username");
username.addEventListener("invalid", ({ target }) => {
  target.setCustomValidity("Hello World!");
});
username.addEventListener("change", ({ target }) => {
  target.setCustomValidity("");
});
```

```html
<form>
<input id="user_username" name="user[username]" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9_-]+" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

You could add this in your Rails view in a similar manner:

```
<%= f.text_field :username, pattern: "[A-Za-z0-9_-]+" %>

...

<script>
const username = document.querySelector("#user_username");
username.addEventListener("invalid", ({ target }) => {
  target.setCustomValidity("Hello World!");
});
username.addEventListener("change", ({ target }) => {
  target.setCustomValidity("");
});
</script>
```

If you need this sort of functionality more often, or want a cleaner solution you might want to write some [unobtrusive JavaScript](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript). For example:

```
function useCustomValidity({ target }) {
  target.setCustomValidity(target.getAttribute("custom-validity"));
}
function clearCustomValidity({ target }) {
  target.setCustomValidity("");
}

document.querySelectorAll("input[custom-validity]").forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener("invalid", useCustomValidity);
  input.addEventListener("change", clearCustomValidity);
});
```

With the above JavaScript being loaded (you need to add additional handlers when using Turbolinks). You can now have the following view:

```
<%= f.text_field :username, pattern: "[A-Za-z0-9_-]+", 'custom-validity': 'Hello World!' %>
```

See also: [MDN Input: Client-side validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Client-side_validation)